# Parenting an object changes transform of its parent

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was trying to set up steering wheel pivot for my spaceship so it rotates correctly. In order to do this I created empty object in the position where I want the pivot(img 1) to be and then parented the steering wheel(img 2) to this pivot. I thought all pivots would stay in the same place in global space and only changes would happen to the steering wheel in local space. I'm confused because it actually changed the position of the pivot as well(img 3), although the only thing I did was parenting the steering wheel to it. Pivot was moved to where steering wheel transform previously was.

img 1
[image: img 1]
img 2
[image: img 2]
img 3
[image: img 3]

Comment: Use empty gameObject as pivot point.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing here and what I have problem with.

Comment: but you pivot object have cube mesh and mesh renderer on it...it is not empty game object.

Comment: That shouldn't matter anyway, but I can check if it changes something.

Comment: Yep, same thing with empty gameobject.

Comment: Hm...ok. Then after parenting just adjust your object position. Don't know why that is happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the tool handle location from *Center* to *Pivot*?
(The switch is located in the top left of the screen near the tool selector)

Also note you can change the location of the tool from *Global* to *Local*.

*Hope this helps,*

Comment: Changing the location from center to pivot fixed this. Thanks!